# nested forms problems on edit, unwanted hidden fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I'm working in Rails2, the helper creates a `hidden_field` which is not helping me...
I load the input like this:

```
  - remote_form_for([:admin, @user]) do |f|
    // [...]
    - f.fields_for :account_user do |a|
      = a.collection_select :id, @accounts, :id, :name}, { :style => "width:330px;"}
```

and I get a result like this:

```
<select style="width: 330px;" name="user[account_user_attributes][id]" id="user_account_user_attributes_id">
    <option value="20">public</option>
    <option value="21">Test Account</option>
    <option value="73">ggg</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" value="175" name="user[account_user_attributes][id]" id="user_account_user_attributes_id">
```

when I reach the controller my params hash is this:

```
(rdb:228) y params
--- !map:HashWithIndifferentAccess 
commit: Save booker
_method: put
action: update
id: "50"
controller: admin/users
user: !map:HashWithIndifferentAccess 
  user_role: agent
  password_confirmation: ""
  username: ERIK
  account_user_attributes: !map:HashWithIndifferentAccess 
    id: "175"
  password: ""
  email: e@visrez.com
```

The value 175 in the hash refers to `@user.account_user.id`, the old value, but I don't have the `@user.account.id` of the new selection.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

**EDIT**

I commented out the collection_select, and the `hidden_field` was still there, therefore... I need to change the title.
If I comment out `f.fields_for` the `hidden_field` disappears.
As pointed out by @jaydel, this is (very) probably the reason why I don't get the right value in the hash. - And the quest goes on...

Actually it's not my code, so now I'm checking for any overriding, as looks like it's not the standard behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we found out that the hidden field was originated by

```
- remote_form_for([:admin, @user]) do |f|
  - f.fields_for :account_user do |a| # <------- here
    = a.collection_select :id, @accounts, :id, :name
```

A better look to the api unvealed the problem, and here is the correct use of `fields_for`:

```
- remote_form_for([:admin, @user]) do |f|
  - f.fields_for @user.account_user do |a|
    = a.collection_select :id, @accounts, :id, :name
```

So the method instead of the symbol.

Note: This code answers the question, but in my case I don't really need any `fields_for` in this relationship.